# How can I determine which link was clicked in my JSP file using Java?

Tags: java, jsp, mouse

In my simple JSP file I have Java code that creates three customers for a bank account. It states their name and a unique number that identifies them. When you launch this in the web browser you can view their name and unique number which is a link. When you click the unique number's link on a certain person, it should redirect you to a new page with that person's specific information. Right now I can view the link but it is the same page for each customer. I need help finding a way for the mouse to detect WHICH unique number was clicked and redirect the user to that specific account information. I am lost and have searched tutorials all over for "User Mouse Input" but it is not quite what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the unique ID as a parameter of the link URL?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can send user id with the link. then u can capture user id and get person's specific information related to the id.

ex link `www.persinDetailsPage.com/?id=person_id`

in java servlet page you can get parameters form request

```
int person_id = req.getParameterValues("person_id");
```

then you can query to get person details using person_id.

Hope this will help.